# Getting Undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get the value from service and then printing that value in console log which is giving me undefined in controller.

The value from service is being returned properly. But I'm not able to access vm.rrsData outside getRRSDetails function. vm.rrsData is comming as undefined outside the function.

Please suggest.

my controller :

```
    (function () {

  'use strict';

  var angular = window.angular;

  function RRSCtrl(
    $translate,
    RRSSvc
  ) {

    var vm = this;

    // Private

    function getRRSDetails() {
      RRSSvc.getRRSDetails()
        .then(function (data) {
          vm.rrsData = data;
        });
    }


    getRRSDetails();

    console.log('vm.rrsData'+ JSON.stringify(vm.rrsData)); // returning undefined here 
  }

  angular
    .module('quote')
    .controller('RRSCtrl', [
      '$translate',
      'RRSSvc',
      RRSCtrl
    ]);

}());
```

my service :

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  var angular = window.angular;

  function RRSSvc(
    $http,
    $q,
    UserSvc,
    UtilitiesSvc
  ) {

    function rrsError(messageKey) {
      UtilitiesSvc.showMessage(messageKey, 'error', 'generate-blank-demo-error');
    }

    function getRRSDetails(poID) {
      return $http.get('quote/accounts/' + UserSvc.get('accountId') + '/pos/' + poID + '/rrs?serialNumber=')
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
          rrsError('quote.messages.GET_RRS_ERROR');
          $q.reject(e);
        });
    }



    return {
      getRRSDetails: getRRSDetails
    };
  }

  angular.module('quote')
    .service('RRSSvc', [
      '$http',
      '$q',
      'UserSvc',
      'UtilitiesSvc',
      RRSSvc
    ]);

}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's completely normal since you're making an asynchronous request.
consider these 2 lines:

```
getRRSDetails();

console.log('vm.rrsData'+ JSON.stringify(vm.rrsData)); // returning undefined here
```

`console.log` will run before the function above resolves. So, at that time `vm.rrsData` is undefined.

To see the value you must include `console.log` inside the function:

```
function getRRSDetails() {
  RRSSvc.getRRSDetails()
    .then(function (data) {
      vm.rrsData = data;
      console.log('vm.rrsData'+ JSON.stringify(vm.rrsData)); // has value from the http call 
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**
Another way to write the above and maybe more clear:

```
RRSSvc.getRRSDetails().then(onRSSDetails);

function onRSSDetails(response) { 
   // here you do whatever you want with data.
   console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: I agree, but how do i get vm.rrsData in controller then? use $timeout?

Comment: you don't know how much time to wait so timeout is not a secure option. What are you trying to do so i can help you more?

Comment: I just want to use vm.rrsData.item in another function within controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your service in controller like this:

```
this.rrsData = null; //declare variavle to store service data

RRSSvc.getRRSDetails()
        .then(function (data) {
          this.rrsData = data;
        }.bind(this)); // bind is the key to store the context

console.log('rrsData'+ JSON.stringify(this.rrsData));
```